# jQuery hover change background image in fixed pozition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello on my project I have a background image

```
background: url('img/1.JPG') fixed;
```

I am trying to change this background image using jQuery when a div `(".boxy")` will be  hoverd.
Here is what i managed to do in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".boxy").hover(
    function()
    {
        $("body").css(??????); //what should i write here in order to change background image in img/2.JPG
    },
    function()
    {
        $("body").css(??????); // what should i write here in order to chage background image in img/1.JPG
    }
);
});
```

Comment: Why dont you add class on hover and remove on mouse out?
`$("body").addClass("hoverd")` and same-wise removeClass("hobved")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".boxy").hover(function () {
        $("body").css('backgroundImage', 'url(img/2.JPG)');
    }, function () {
        $("body").css('backgroundImage', 'url(img/1.JPG)');
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xP86s/)**

Comment: `backgroundImage` this looks like a property used in `javascript` rather than a property used in `CSS`?

Comment: @KingKing - per the docs, "Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css( "background-color" ) and .css( "backgroundColor" )."

Comment: the upvote sign (up triangle) is orange now. I will toggle it for you to see?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

something like this !

Comment: it dosent work how it should be, i have in css  "background: url('img/1.JPG') fixed;" but not "background-image: url('img/1.JPG') fixed;" and it should be fixed like in my css

Comment: Just remove -image.

$('body').css('background', 'url(' + imageUrl + ') fixed');

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').css("background", "url('/image.jpg') fixed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".boxy").hover(
function()
{
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(/img.png)");
},
function()
{
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(/img2.png)");
}
);
});
```